# Boosting Hyperparameter for LightGBM: does 'goss' use 'gbdt' as underlying model?

Tags: lightgbm

For the "boosting" parameter in lightgbm: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html, is 'gbdt' used as the underlying model for 'goss'?

Comment: From https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/0a4a7a86f5a1d3146c36c7d8c082154a193d4893/src/boosting/goss.hpp, it seems goss is derived from gbdt

Answer (score 1):

GOSS is a weighted sampling version of GBDT.

please refer to the GOSS algorithm in LightGBM Paper: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradi